# How do I combine two jQuery event handlers in to one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is that I have two event handlers who do the same thing but for different objects. Could someone tell me how to do this.

```
$('.url1').keyup(function() {
  var limit = 60; // Maximale Anzahl an Zeichen
  var count = $(this).val().length;

  $('.counter').html(count);
  if (count > limit) {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'crimson');
  } else {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'ForestGreen');
  }

});

$('.title1').keyup(function() {
  var limit = 45; // Maximale Anzahl an Zeichen
  var count = $(this).val().length;

  $('.counter').html(count);
  if (count > limit) {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'crimson');
  } else {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'ForestGreen');
  }
});
```

Comment: but now there is var limit = 45; for bouth 45 and i want that there have different limits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between your elements is the `limit` you set. So you can apply the same function to both elements and place the `limit` in a `data` attribute on the element itself which can be read when the event fires. Something like this:

```js
$('.url1, .title1').keyup(function() {
  var limit = $(this).data('limit');
  var count = $(this).val().length;

  $('.counter').html(count);
  if (count > limit) {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'crimson');
  } else {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'ForestGreen');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Url: <input class="url1" type="text" data-limit="60" /><br />
Title: <input class="title1" type="text" data-limit="45" /><br />

<div class="counter"></div>
```

Comment: You beat me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a list-based selector and a bit of logic to set your limit variable based on whether the 'url1' class is present.

```
$('.url1,.title1').keyup(function() {

  var limit = $(this).hasClass("url1") ? 60 : 45; // Maximale Anzahl an Zeichen

  var count = $(this).val().length;

  $('.counter').html(count);
  if (count > limit) {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'crimson');
  } else {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'ForestGreen');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply factor out a separate function that's parameterized based on `limit`, and call that from your event handlers:

```
function checkLimit($el, limit) {
  var count = $el.val().length;

  $('.counter').html(count);
  if (count > limit) {
    $el.css('border-color', 'crimson');
  } else {
    $el.css('border-color', 'ForestGreen');
  }
}

$('.url1').keyup(function() {
    checkLimit($(this), 60);
});

$('.title1').keyup(function() {
    checkLimit($(this), 45);
});
```

You could also go one step further and use a function that creates your event handler functions with the limits "baked in":

```
function checkLimitHandler(limit) {
    return function () {
        var count = $(this).val().length;

        $('.counter').html(count);
        if (count > limit) {
            $(this).css('border-color', 'crimson');
        } else {
            $(this).css('border-color', 'ForestGreen');
        }
    };
}

$('.url1').keyup(checkLimitHandler(60));

$('.title1').keyup(checkLimitHandler(45));
```